# Scheduling tasks with Django

Tags: python, django

I have a site I'm working on that I'd like to add an option to sign up for a weekly newsletter type thing. I did a lot of looking around, and I was wondering if the python schedule library is an okay thing to use for this (https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Could I have my website running and then a scheduler running in tandem that runs a django management command to send emails to those who sign up? I'm fairly new to this kind of thing, so I just wanted to check since I couldn't really find any info of other people doing this.

I have a script that sends emails and when I use the scheduler to send them every however many minutes it works, but I'm just wondering about the scalability of this. I think I'd like to avoid using something like celery since it seems like sort of a big solution to a small problem.

Comment: Your approach is ok. You probably have schedule services in your production PaaS or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

I would say celery is often an overkill, especially if you are running a single task because it requires a message transport server and the library has a lot of unnecessary features for a simple use case.

I would recommand to use `django-q2` which provides a full django admin integration and can run using your app database.

Answer (score 0):

I think Celery is a great option to achieve your goal.
You will also need another tools, according to the docs:

> Celery requires a message transport to send and receive messages. The RabbitMQ and Redis broker transports are feature complete, but there’s also support for a myriad of other experimental solutions, including using SQLite for local development.

Take a look at the rest of [the doc](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html)

Comment: But is there a reason that celery would be better than just using the library that I'm using?

Comment: Schedule docs:

Let’s be honest, Schedule is not a ‘one size fits all’ scheduling library. This library is designed to be a simple solution for simple scheduling problems. You should probably look somewhere else if you need:

    Job persistence (remember schedule between restarts)
    Exact timing (sub-second precision execution)
    Concurrent execution (multiple threads)
    Localization (workdays or holidays)

Schedule does not account for the time it takes for the job function to execute.

Comment: The main reason I use celery is for it's third party libraries. With Django_celery_beat, I can schedule tasks at runtime, no need to restart the Django app. With django celery results, if you are a site administrator it can give you great insights about which tasks ran for how long, with what arguments and when they failed. Celery is often overkill, if you are doing this for a client - probably don't for such a simple/single task. If you are experimenting with your own projects, give it a try. You won't regret it, and it WILL help you in the future with client projects.

Comment: You can also set it up so it wont have to check every so often, but it gets scheduled when you want. You can invoke the task - it will run asynchronously on your machine, or another and probably be better than checking an empty queue every so often. What are you going to do if you *NEED* scaling? Will refactoring your current solution to work across multiple server work? Should this be something to consider beforehand? This again - all depends on the nature of your project.